# Using a noun phrase or a verb phrase as topic sentence

Tags: verbs, nouns, sentence, phrase-usage

Can I start a topic sentence with a verb phrase or a noun phrase? For example:

> Firstly, improve their eating habits. ....
>
> Secondly, improve their physical lifestyles. ...

or

> Firstly, the decline in birth rate. ....
>
> Secondly, lack of exercise. ...

Comment: It's not really helpful to think of your "improve" examples as "starting with a verb phrase". They're ***imperative*** sentences, preceded by the implied but **unstated** subject noun ***you*** (the structure is **[S]VO** rather than **SVO**).

Comment: Strictly speaking, those sentences each begin with a single word—an adverb. The first sentence is an independent clause with or without it. The second sentence is not an independent clause, and wouldn't be considered a standard sentence. But if it's a *title* of some kind, or if it's put in the right context, the sentence fragment may be quite acceptable. So, it's not completely clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Examples three and four are not sentences but noun (on some analyses, determiner in at least example 3) **phrases** (each following an ordering pragmatic marker).

Answer (score -1):

Not a verb phrase, though you can turn it into a noun phrase with a gerund "Firstly, improving their eating habits."

The noun phrase examples are grammatically ok but might be a bit short on information, depending on what you're writing and how it's introduced.  If you set it up clearly with something like:

"This is due to two main factors: the decline in birth rate, and lack of exercise.  Each of these will now be dealt with in turn.

Firstly, the decline in birth rate.  This has been a problem since..."

it should be ok.  It's difficult to be more helpful without knowing a bit more about what it is you're writing.